# arrow length and text placing to left in tikzcd

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I am trying this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]

A \arrow[r, "aaa"] \arrow[d, "xxxx"] &   B  \arrow[d, "yyyy"] \\ 

C                           & D  \arrow[l, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"] \\

\end{tikzcd}

\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

and I would like to fix 2 things:

1) The arrow over the "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" label should be longer, so the pic does not look so cramped.
2) I would like the "xxxx" label to be on the left of the down arrow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,column sep=width("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")]
A \arrow[r, "aaa"] \arrow[d, "\mathrm{xxxx}" swap] &   B  \arrow[d,
"\mathrm{yyyy}"] \\ 
C                           & D  \arrow[l, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The arrow length over the "bbbbbbb" is perfect, thank you. But I want the "xxx" label to be at the same height as the "yyyyy" label, but to the left of the A to C downarrow.

Comment: @district9 Yes, in the updated version it is there. (I misread your question first.)

Comment: Almost there, I just need to make the label on the arrow in roman. I tried to replace the \arrow[d, "yyyy"] with \arrow[d, {\rm "yyyy"}], but it does not seem to compile. Thanks!

Comment: @district9 Sorry, was offline. You need to put the information inside the quotes (and `\mathrm` is more appropriate than `\rm`). I made `xxxx` and `yyy` upright. There also different options like `\text` or `\mathup`, it depends on what you really aim at.

Answer (score 2):

From the [TikZ manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), Section *20.3.2 Setting and Adjusting Column and Row Spacing*

> The cell separation character `&` also takes an optional argument, which
>   must also be a spacing list. This spacing list is added to the column
>   sep having a similar effect as the option for the `\\` command for rows.
>   This optional spacing list can only be given the first time a new
>   column is started (usually in the first row), subsequent usages of
>   this option in later rows have no effect.

In practice, if you put a `[<width>]` after `&`, for example `&[7em]`, you can enlarge the space between the two columns separated by `&[<width>]` as you wish.

The option `column sep=<width>` sets a default spacing for *all* columns.

This difference could be relevant in case you have a matrix with more than two columns. If you want to enlarge only the space between the first and the second columns, but not between the second and the third, `&[<width>]` should be used, not `column sep=<width>`.

Option `swap` to change the position of the label.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
A \arrow[r, "aaa"] \arrow[d, "xxxx", swap] &[7em]   B  \arrow[d, "yyyy"] \\ 
C                           & D  \arrow[l, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]